# IE session issue while using iframe as form target and image source blank

Tags: html, internet-explorer, session

when form target set to iframe source and after posting form content you are setting session variables,
In this scenario if parent page having image src blank then session values set in iframe action page will

be LOST surprisingly in IE ONLY.Solution is quite simple Image src can't keep blank

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="">
        <form action="test.php" method="post" target="iframe_page">
            FORM CONTENT
        </form>
    <iframe src="blank.php" name="iframe_page" >
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quite simple. Do no keep Image src blank.