# Losing PHP sessions in iFrame with Chrome & IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, google-chrome

**Question:**

I am having issues passing session variables from parent page to iFrame page and AJAX called PHP files in Chrome & IE. It seems to work in FF and Safari though.

**Environment:**

I have Wordpress as my "Portal". One of my Wordpress pages is a "Dashboard". That Dashboard makes AJAX requests against a CRM web service to render JSON data. Wordpress, the Dashboard file and the CRM are all on the same domain. "www.domain.com/wordpress" is the Wordpress domain, "www.domain.com/dashboard/dashboard.php" is the Dashboard file which is included via iFrame on a Wordpress page, and "www.domain.com/CRM/webservice.php" is the web service file I'm making AJAX calls against.

**Approach:**

User logs into Wordpress using LDAP. I grab the username from Wordpress and dump it into a `$_SESSION['WPUsername']` variable as an extension to Wordpress' login function. Then, when my Dashboard loads in the iFrame, it makes a request to my CRM web service file via jQuery `$.get()`. The `webservice.php` receives the request, then uses the `$_SESSION['WPUsername']` session variable to internally query the appropriate data and return the response.

**Problem:**

Firefox is working fine. IE & Chrome seem to think the `$_SESSION['WPUsername']` doesn't exist when requested by `webservice.php`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a note...everything is on the same server in addition to being on the same domain.

Comment: another good reason to stop using (i)frames.

Comment: Temporary solution to a bigger project that will do away with iFrames.

Comment: It would actually be PHP that does not recognize the session variable. If I had to guess, your session cookie is limited to a certain path within your website, which does not get passed to the other subdirectories.

Comment: @NickCaballero Your comment is absolute non-sense.

Comment: If the cookie path is /, it should work fine. However, if the cookie path is a subdirectory, like /wordpress, other subdirectories will not have the cookie. http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path

Comment: look if this will help..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6455315/ie-session-issue-while-using-iframe-as-form-target-and-image-source-blank

Comment: is the domain name in the frame? calling a domain from a frame is treated as different site so /dashboard/dashboard.php not www.domain.com/dashboard/dashboard.php hope I have understood correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made all of the recommended changes to my PHP configuration and website. I set the cookie path in php.ini to "/" and I used the full subdomain path ("www.domain.com/dashboard/dashboard.php") in my iFrames. It seems to be working fine now.

On another note, I just implemented SSO using OpenAM as the IdP and SimpleSAMLphp as the SP. No need for session cookies to manage authentication anymore and all data passed between components is now done using web services.